# Feedback loop in Web Audio API

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I'm working on some sound effect with delay which I have created using delayNode and a feedback loop. However this seems to be infinite loop and after some time (pretty quick) audio starts to lag and then stops completely with a crunch.

```
source.connect(delayNode);
delayNode.connect(someMoreEffects);
someMoreEffects.connect(delayNode);
source.connect(context.destination);
delayNode.connect(context.destination);
```

How can I limit the amount of passes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not really clear what you mean by "starts to lag", "crunch", and "amount of passes", but if you want to stop the feedback loop, disconnect the source from the delay node and/or the delay node from the destination.  Or some variation of this.  Or insert a gain node in the feedback loop and set the gain to 0 at some appropriate time; this will stop the feedback too.

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I haven't thought of setting a timeout to disconnect the feedback loop. Silly me :)

Comment: Generally, you'll want to do Raymond's second suggestion - put a gain node between the "someMoreEffects" and the loop back into the delayNode, and set the gain to less than one.  This is the "feedback" control that delay units always have, and it is nearly always set to less than one (so the sound fades away eventually).

Comment: Thanks @cwilso. Yes, I ended up doing that. I have found an issue in my chain where gain never faded to low enough levels